# How to set blur for an element programmatically?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to set blur for a button programmatically with Angular 1.5, 
I think that `ng-blur` cannot help me because it's like an event that I do something only when the element is not in focus (blur).
I also tried `var elem = angular.element(document.querySelector("button"));
   elem.blur();` 
but it doesn't work.

Is there any easy way to set blur programmatically?

Comment: Did you try just `document.querySelector("button").blur()`

Comment: What do you mean with _"set blur"_? Do you want to call the blur event?

Comment: @adeneo No, tried it now and it works, thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27234110/3153169

Comment: `elem[0].blur();`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Blur an input field on keypress enter on Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27234110/blur-an-input-field-on-keypress-enter-on-angular)